# How to use NOT IN clause in filter condition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter a column of an RDD source  :

```
val source = sql("SELECT * from sample.source").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
val destination = sql("select * from sample.destination").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))

val source_primary_key = source.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0)))
val destination_primary_key = destination.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0)))

val src = source_primary_key.subtractByKey(destination_primary_key)
```

I want to use IN clause in filter condition to filter out only the values present in src from source, something like below(EDITED):

```
val source = spark.read.csv(inputPath + "/source").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
val destination = spark.read.csv(inputPath + "/destination").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))

val source_primary_key = source.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0)))
val destination_primary_key = destination.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0)))

val extra_in_source = source_primary_key.filter(rec._1 != destination_primary_key._1)
```

equivalent SQL code is

```
SELECT * FROM SOURCE WHERE ID IN (select ID from src)
```

Thank you

Comment: what are the types of your values ?

Comment: That's not what I asked for. What is the type of 'src' or 'source' ? Are you working with RDDs or DataFrame ?

Comment: Edit your post adding the type for each variable please.

Comment: and why don't you use spark sql directly ? sql return structured data

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since your code isn't reproducible, here is a small example using `spark-sql` on how to `select * from t where id in (...)` :

```
// create a DataFrame for a range 'id' from 1 to 9.
scala> val df = spark.range(1,10).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint]

// values to exclude
scala> val f = Seq(5,6,7)
f: Seq[Int] = List(5, 6, 7)

// select * from df where id is not in the values to exclude
scala> df.filter(!col("id").isin(f  : _*)).show
+---+                                                                           
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+

// select * from df where id is in the values to exclude
scala> df.filter(col("id").isin(f  : _*)).show
```

Here is the RDD version of the `not isin` :

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val f = Seq(5,6,7)
f: Seq[Int] = List(5, 6, 7)

scala> val rdd2 = rdd.filter(x => !f.contains(x))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at <console>:28
```

Nevertheless, I still believe this is an overkill since you are already using `spark-sql`.

It seems in your case that you are actually dealing with DataFrames, thus the solutions mentioned above don't work.

You can use the left anti join approach :

```
scala> val source = spark.read.format("csv").load("source.file")
source: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 9 more fields]

scala> val destination = spark.read.format("csv").load("destination.file")
destination: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 9 more fields]

scala> source.show
+---+------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---+---+----------+-----+---------+------------+
|_c0|               _c1|     _c2|       _c3|            _c4|_c5|_c6|       _c7|  _c8|      _c9|        _c10|
+---+------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---+---+----------+-----+---------+------------+
|  1|        Ravi kumar|   Ravi |     kumar|           MSO |  1|  M|17-01-1994| 74.5| 24000.78|    Alabama |
|  2|Shekhar shudhanshu| Shekhar|shudhanshu|      Manulife |  2|  M|18-01-1994|76.34|   250000|     Alaska |
|  3|Preethi Narasingam| Preethi|Narasingam|        Retail |  3|  F|19-01-1994|77.45|270000.01|    Arizona |
|  4|     Abhishek Nair|Abhishek|      Nair|       Banking |  4|  M|20-01-1994|78.65|   345000|   Arkansas |
|  5|        Ram Sharma|     Ram|    Sharma|Infrastructure |  5|  M|21-01-1994|79.12|    45000| California |
|  6|   Chandani Kumari|Chandani|    Kumari|          BNFS |  6|  F|22-01-1994|80.13| 43000.02|   Colorado |
|  7|      Balaji Kumar|  Balaji|     Kumar|           MSO |  1|  M|23-01-1994|81.33|  1234678|Connecticut |
|  8|  Naveen Shekrappa|  Naveen| Shekrappa|      Manulife |  2|  M|24-01-1994|  100|   789414|   Delaware |
|  9|     Milind Chavan|  Milind|    Chavan|        Retail |  3|  M|25-01-1994|83.66|   245555|    Florida |
| 10|      Raghu Rajeev|   Raghu|    Rajeev|       Banking |  4|  M|26-01-1994|87.65|   235468|     Georgia|
+---+------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---+---+----------+-----+---------+------------+


scala> destination.show
+---+-------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---+---+----------+-----+---------+------------+
|_c0|                _c1|     _c2|       _c3|            _c4|_c5|_c6|       _c7|  _c8|      _c9|        _c10|
+---+-------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---+---+----------+-----+---------+------------+
|  1|         Ravi kumar|   Revi |     kumar|           MSO |  1|  M|17-01-1994| 74.5| 24000.78|    Alabama |
|  1|        Ravi1 kumar|   Revi |     kumar|           MSO |  1|  M|17-01-1994| 74.5| 24000.78|    Alabama |
|  1|        Ravi2 kumar|   Revi |     kumar|           MSO |  1|  M|17-01-1994| 74.5| 24000.78|    Alabama |
|  2| Shekhar shudhanshu| Shekhar|shudhanshu|      Manulife |  2|  M|18-01-1994|76.34|   250000|     Alaska |
|  3|Preethi Narasingam1| Preethi|Narasingam|        Retail |  3|  F|19-01-1994|77.45|270000.01|    Arizona |
|  4|     Abhishek Nair1|Abhishek|      Nair|       Banking |  4|  M|20-01-1994|78.65|   345000|   Arkansas |
|  5|         Ram Sharma|     Ram|    Sharma|Infrastructure |  5|  M|21-01-1994|79.12|    45000| California |
|  6|    Chandani Kumari|Chandani|    Kumari|          BNFS |  6|  F|22-01-1994|80.13| 43000.02|   Colorado |
|  7|       Balaji Kumar|  Balaji|     Kumar|           MSO |  1|  M|23-01-1994|81.33|  1234678|Connecticut |
|  8|   Naveen Shekrappa|  Naveen| Shekrappa|      Manulife |  2|  M|24-01-1994|  100|   789414|   Delaware |
|  9|      Milind Chavan|  Milind|    Chavan|        Retail |  3|  M|25-01-1994|83.66|   245555|    Florida |
| 10|       Raghu Rajeev|   Raghu|    Rajeev|       Banking |  4|  M|26-01-1994|87.65|   235468|     Georgia|
+---+-------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---+---+----------+-----+---------+------------+
```

You'll just need to do the following :

```
scala> val res1 = source.join(destination, Seq("_c0"), "leftanti")

scala> val res2 = destination.join(source, Seq("_c0"), "leftanti")
```

It's the same logic I mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887526/filter-spark-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe-that-specifies-blacklist-crite/39889263#39889263).

Comment: @eliasha, Im using RDD not dataframe

Comment: am looking for something like val extra_in_source = source_primary_key.filter(rec != destination_primary_key._1)

Comment: I'm still not convinced on the reason of using DataFrame if they are available to use. Let me update my answer anyway

Comment: I have updated the question what I'm looking for exactly

Comment: I have (1,2,3,4) in source_primary_key and I have (1,2,3) in destination_primary_key, I need a filter for extra in source i.e (4)  something like val extra_In_source = source_primary_key.filter(NOT IN (destination_primary_key)), the above is just a pseudo code for what I'm looking for

Comment: If you don't post actual data example, I can't give you actual code. I can give you a code example.

Comment: I have updated the question section with my actual code, I'm looking for NOT IN but the solution you provided is for IN clause

Comment: I'm using RDD[String], so its not allowing to use contains method. I got this error value contains is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: I got this error value contains is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Comment: You can't use an RDD inside of an RDD transformation

Comment: I have two datasets source and destination, I don't want use the whole data for transformation so I just took the primary key alone using something like  `val source_primary_key = source.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0)))
    val destination_primary_key = destination.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0)))` after that I want to find out extra in source that are the values which are not present in destination. so I need a NOT IN clause to do that and vice versa for to find extra in destination. Please let me know if you need further more clarification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148303/discussion-between-eliasah-and-vignesh).

Answer (score 8):

You can try like--

```
df.filter(~df.Dept.isin("30","20")).show()
```

//This will list all the columns of df where Dept NOT IN 30 or 20

Comment: @BdEngineer The above code is applicable in PySpark only

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar in Java,

```
ds = ds.filter(functions.not(functions.col(COLUMN_NAME).isin(exclusionSet)));
```

where exclusionSet is a set of objects that needs to be removed from your dataset.