# PySpark: opposite of .dropna()?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to find which shop has an 'empty' day, i.e. a day where no customer came.

My table has the following structure:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| shop     | 2020-10-15  | 2020-10-16  | 2020-10-17  | 2020-10-18  | 2020-10-19  | 2020-10-20  | 2020-10-21 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Paris    | 215         | 213         | 128         | 102         | 195         | 180         |        110 |
| London   | 145         | 106         | 102         | 83          | 127         | 111         |         56 |
| Beijing  | 179         | 245         | 134         | 136         | 207         | 183         |        136 |
| Sydney   | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 6           |         36 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

With pandas I can do something like `customers[customers== 0].dropna(how="all")` and that will keep only the rows where there is a `0`, and I get this:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| shop     | 2020-10-15  | 2020-10-16  | 2020-10-17  | 2020-10-18  | 2020-10-19  | 2020-10-20  | 2020-10-21 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Sydney   | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | NaN         |         NaN|
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

In PySpark I believe [`.dropna()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna) does something similar but I want to do the opposite, keep the NA/0 values. How can I do that?

Comment: you can make new data frame from dropna() of first dataframe and then use left anti join between these two dataframe.
look this page for left anti join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887526/filter-spark-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe-that-specifies-denylist-criter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating sample dataset:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_list= [
  { "shop":"Paris", "2020-10-15" : 215,"2020-10-16": 213, "2020-10-17" : 128,"2020-10-18": 195,"2020-10-19":195},
{"shop":"London", "2020-10-15" : 145,"2020-10-16": 106, "2020-10-17" : 102,"2020-10-18": 127,"2020-10-19":127},
 { "shop":"Beijing ", "2020-10-15" : 179,"2020-10-16": 245, "2020-10-17" : 136,"2020-10-18": 207,"2020-10-19":207},

 {"shop":"Sydney", "2020-10-15" : 0,"2020-10-16": 0 ,"2020-10-17" : 0,"2020-10-18": 0, "2020-10-19":0}

]
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in df_list)
df.show()
```

--

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    shop|2020-10-15|2020-10-16|2020-10-17|2020-10-18|2020-10-19|
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   Paris|       215|       213|       128|       195|       195|
|  London|       145|       106|       102|       127|       127|
|Beijing |       179|       245|       136|       207|       207|
|  Sydney|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

You can apply the filter function

```
df.filter(f.greatest(*[f.col(i).isin(0) for i in df.columns])).show()
```

result:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  shop|2020-10-15|2020-10-16|2020-10-17|2020-10-18|2020-10-19|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Sydney|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I prefer not having to iterate over all columns. I want a solution that can work with any number of columns.

Comment: i have modified the code, hope this meets your requirement

Comment: Oh this is great, I think I can use that! Just a quick remark, we don't need to use `isin(0)` since there's only one value to test. Using `f.col(i) == 0` may work, right?